# Installshield limited edition asking for .Net framework files and program not running without visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, installshield-le

I have a solution in VS 2013 community edition, an I recently added a setup project with Installshield limited edition.

When I re-build the solution (On release x64 mode) the installshield project warns me about the following files:

```
Warning -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework.  It is recommended that the release include the .NET Framework. 16  ISEXP : warning : -6245: One or more of the project's components contain .NET properties that require the .NET Framework.  It is recommended that the release include the .NET Framework.

Warning -6248: Could not find dependent file Microsoft.ServiceBus, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output    18  ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file Microsoft.ServiceBus, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output

Warning -6248: Could not find dependent file Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeMarkers.dll, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output  19  ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeMarkers.dll, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output

Warning -6248: Could not find dependent file Newtonsoft.Json, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output 20  ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file Newtonsoft.Json, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output

Warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Data.SQLite, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output  21  ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Data.SQLite, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output

Warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Net.Http.Formatting, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output  22  ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Net.Http.Formatting, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output

Warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Web.Http, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output 23  ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Web.Http, or one of its dependencies of component PLATOS.Primary_output
```

On the Installshield setup wizzard I selected that the setup looks for .Net 4.5. so I do not understand those warnings.

When I install the software with the setup in a computer that has no Visual Studio installed (but has the latest Net framework (4.5.2)) the program opens (I see that in the task manager) and closes without showing the GUI. Moreover, when I just copy the `\bin\release` folder to a computer with no Visual studio, the program still won't run.

My guess is that somehow the program requires for the files that installshield is warning me about, but Shouldn't those files be installed by the .Net 4.5 already?

I have seen other threads where the problem is solved by compiling in release mode, but I am already doing that, so I have no clue of what might be wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the main project a WebForms roject; MVC; etc...?

Comment: PS, if you've previously used the Visual Studio installer, it is still available but must be installed separately: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d; who knows - maybe that would solve the problem in a totally different way.

Comment: Hi I changed the installer to the Visual Studio installer and the problem persists. only that now, it throws a file not found exception.

Comment: Probalby offtopic: We had several issues with Installshield LE and we switched to WiX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a very long time, I found the problem.

First and just to be sure, install all the dependencies using the NuGet manager. (Whenever possible)

Then as in my case I had C++ wrapped with C++CLI and I use VS 2013, install [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) manually.

This made the program to execute properly on a fresh formatted windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your program seems to be referencing the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeMarkers` assembly, which, as its name implies, is not distributed in the framework .Net, but with Visual Studio.

In your solution, you can check out the references of your project by opening the "References" folder. Remove `Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeMarkers`, build your project, see what breaks. Of right click on this reference, select "properties", and in the property pane, in the "local copy" field, select "True". Do the same for `Microsoft.ServiceBus`.

Also, make sure your nuget packages (like Newtonsoft.Json) are included for distribution in your InstallShield installer.

Comment: On the same "references" tab mentioned, there is a button to show unused references and remove them; it's good practice to do that too.

Comment: No, there is not (or I did not find it with VS2013). I'm pretty sure this is a feature added by an add-on like Resharper or JustCode.

Comment: I've double checked and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeMarkers' is not in the application references, but maybe it is on some of the libraries I used on it. Where do I see the complete dependency tree?

Comment: Sorry, different spot: to remove unused references: right-click on the project and select properties... that will open a huge dialog with several tabs; select the "References" tab... that's where you will find all project references and be able to removed all unused references.

Comment: I use VS 2013 community, and in the C# properties there's no references tab, only Reference Paths and it is empty for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your install script and I will help you. 
We need to know whether this solution has ever been built successfully on ANY machine before we troubleshoot whether your installshield LE is corrupt, generating wrong files, calling incorrect dll's, or has instabilities somewhere.

If the solution has never left this system, and has built successfully at some point, then you might have legitimate files in your bin, but the temp folder under your MS .Net Framework folder containing the wrong files (but let us not go there yet).

You mentioned you are in release already, so some questions:

(1) Was this solution pulled from another machine with Windows Visual Studio SDK installed?

(2) Was this solution built with the command line builder originally?

(3) If the solution was moved, was there any other packages which complained when restored but was not on the error list above? (It may have shown on output only for example).

(4) When you are in the Installshield UI, do you see any missing dependencies?

Please make sure you went through the restoring packages step when the solution was loaded.

I recommend installing the Visual Studio SDK to see if you get more clues or narrow down the problem.

To clarify, checking for restored package errors AND installing the SDK are important troubleshooting steps based on what you have told us so far.

The next logical step is to confirm the dependencies from scan at build time and / or any packages that were restored are properly referenced so you can narrow down this long list of complaining packages (which is just muddling the matter IMHO).

I almost hate to mention this because it is more of a workaround dependent upon whether you have ever had a successfull build on this system, but if worse comes to worse, you could use the Installshield UI to add the latest DLL in your obj\Release folder and build again.

The paid version used to have a fully working sample project, but I have not used installshield in a couple of years.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have had several successful builds (actually hundreds) , and I have distributed the software to colleagues using it, but on the requisite that they install VS, because otherwise it wont work. On the other questions I have developed the solution using VS 2012 and later 2013 community edition, often collaborative wit other colleagues using SVN.

Comment: OK, then you should make a restore point, install the Visual Studio SDK, restart, open the solution, and check to see if any errors go away after any package restores.  Do NOT change any build settings or disable any build notifications, etc.  THEN go clear the the temp folder under your MS .Net Framework folder. Then rebuild. Installshield is notorious for finding older DLLs and you do not want to get a contaminated build.  Let me know how that works out because if worse comes to worse you can try to reference the last known good DLL from your obj\Release folder in the Installshield UI later.

Comment: Just to clarify, we are following this troubleshooting path with the Visual Studio SDK install first because we are trying to narrow this down logically.  Trying the workaround of referencing the last know good DLL via the obj\Release folder is a last resort, so we need to focus on what the Installshield UI shows under "Dependencies from scan at build" first (in case you have any new errors).  We do not want your build to have any loose ends because you do not want to end up in the same boat later if you were to import into a later version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi, I reinstalled the SDK 7, rebooted and the error persists. clicking on Dependencies from scan at build, I get the list of dependencies from which the .dll files I indicated at the top are not found, even when I add those DLL files manually to the installation.

Comment: If you did not get any new build errors (emphasis on new), then unfortunately it is time to resort to referencing the last known good DLL from your obj\Release folder in the Installshield UI to see if it will work again.  Sorry the Installshield guys cannot seem to get their collective act together and support someone who is a solid user as you obviously are.  I wish I could help you further, but this is all I know to do my friend.

Comment: Thanks, lately I tried to install all the packages that Installshield claimed as missing from the NuGet repository and those seem to be recognized by Installshield, however I have not yet completed the process. Iĺ report back if I get this to work.

Comment: Yes, let us know -- you may get more insight and / or a new error - - I do not think yours is a typical case.  Has anything else unusual during your other builds complained after you installed the Visual Studio SDK?

Comment: No, actually after reinstalling the SDK, I had the exact same errors.